# Error al utilizar barryvdh / laravel-snappy

Tags: php, laravel

Hola recién estoy comenzando a utilizar [laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) para generar PDF, ya que dompf se tarda demasiado cuando son muchas hojas hasta el punto de no cargar el PDF, entonces hice lo siguente:

Ruta:

```
Route::get('fac-list-pdf', 'FacturasController@exportPdf')->name('facturas.pdf');
```

Controller

```
use Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf as PDF;

public function exportPdf()
{

    $facturas = Factura::all();
    return \PDF::loadView('pdf.facturas')->stream('facturas.pdf'); 
}
```

Index de facturas (creé este botón):

```
<a href="{{ route('facturas.pdf') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Facturas PDF</a>
```

Pero cuando hago clic en el botón Facturas PDF me dice:

> 404 Not Found

¿Me podrían por favor orientar para saber que error tengo? De antemano gracias por la ayuda que puedan prestarme, saludos.

Comment: Puede ser ese return, no veo en la documentación que exista ese método stream. Puedes probar con `$pdf = PDF::loadView(pdf.facturas', $facturas);
return $pdf->download('facturas.pdf');` .

Comment: Hola, hice lo que me dijiste pero sigue igual, el metodo stream es para ver en pantalla, te recuerdo que estoy usando snappy por si te confundes con Dompf, te hago una consulta, tienes alguna sugerencia para hacer que Dompdf carga 5000 registros rapido?, estoy tratando de usar este porque es muy lento el Dompdf y cuando hay muchos registros no carga.

Comment: Igual fué un lance nada más, dándole una leída rápida, 404 Not Found, parecería más un problema de rutas, pero en lo que pusiste en la pregunta, eso parece estar correcto.

Comment: Si ese es el repositorio, si pienso lo mismo que es algo de rutas pero todo bien configurado.

Comment: Por las dudas re chequea que no tengas otra ruta con el mismo nombre `facturas.pdf`.

Comment: Hola, no tengo otra ruta con ese nombre, gracias por tu ayuda